# How to get the module from which the currently executing function was called?

Tags: python, introspection

This is my best solution so far to the problem of accessing the calling module from within a function:

```
import inspect
import sys
def calling_module(level=0):
    filename = inspect.stack()[level+2][1]
    modulename = inspect.getmodulename(filename)
    try:
        return sys.modules[modulename]
    except KeyError:
        return sys.modules['__main__']
```

...but implicit in the handling of the `KeyError` is the (largely unfounded) assumption that it can happen only if `filename` is being run as `__main__`.

Does the Python standard library provide a more robust way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find that the following works well:

```
import inspect
def printfunc()
    stk = inspect.stack()[1]
    mod = inspect.getmodule(stk[0])
    print("Currently in {}.{}".format(mod, stk[3]))
```

which I have inside a utility function called something like `printfunc()`